# What is the best way to handle big number returning from database in nodeJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a node JS application getting data from MySql Database. Column type of one the column is bigint(20). This will return a big integer value and this is going out of javascript number range. What is the best way to handle this?

Sample code

```
let rows = database.query("select resourcekey from resourceTable");

for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  console.log(rows[i].resourcekey);
}
```

Sample resourceKey : 9220610450398789367
Value returned : 9220610450398790000

Comment: You would need to use a library like [BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodeJS mysql provides supportBigNumbers and bigNumberStrings configuration options. Enabling both of this will force to return big numbers(BIGINT and Decimal) to be returned as javascript string.

```
let dbConnection = mysql.createConnection({supportBigNumbers: true, bigNumberStrings: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making your calculations on the programming side, i.e., Node JS, store the content as `VARCHAR(50)` and parse it as Integer in Node JS:

```
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  console.log(parseInt(rows[i].resourcekey));
}
```

MySQL is messing up the huge integer value and you don't require unless you are performing mathematical operations in the MySQL Server itself.

Comment: `9220610450398789367` exceeds the range of an integer so  `parseInt(9220610450398789367)` will be `9220610450398790000`, so this will not solve anything.

Comment: @t.niese True that... Is there any other solution then? We can just tell the OP if they aren't doing anything with the number, they should leave it as string. And yep [**this is strange!**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z1oW.png)

Comment: There is no business logic on resourceKey column. But it is a legacy table with millions of rows of data. Can not change the datatype of column to Varchar(50)

Comment: @ConfusedCoder Sorry mate, then it's NOT possible at all to get the value. Is the value stored, intact in its value?

Comment: Data gets added to this table from java application. In java it is handled as bigInteger. I am writing a migration code in nodejs.